# How to embed Apache Spark (Scala) in HTML?

Tags: html, css, scala, apache-spark

As a working PHP Developer, I came across to work with Big Data, I choose to work with Apache Spark (Scala) for Excel file read and write. I want to display all file data in table format, is that possible to do with html, css and jQuery, if yes please share an example.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Excel files are typically so small that you can parse it with non-big-data framework

Comment: Files I have, they are around 4GB+, and I want to parse them in few seconds, is it possible to work with the non-big-data framework?

Comment: Sp-ark is a processing engine. Your HTML have to call some API that launches Spark job and reads output after finished job. It's not possible AFAIK to launch Spark in browser, but next day - next JS framework, so who knows ;)

Comment: Okay! So, any example to run a spark scala script on the server?

Comment: Did you search for tutorials?

Comment: Yes, I did but not able to initiate spark-shell and load .scala file in a single terminal command. I created a 'test.sh' file, that is initiating spark-shell but not executing :load command.